# Getting dataframe records that do not exist in second data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes with uniqueid's.  Based on the ID comparison, I would like to get the records from df1 that do not exist in df2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a dupe. Use: `df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]`

Comment: Not the best answer. See the second answer in the linked question.